Java program not producing expected output with synchronized method in multithreading
Problem:
I'm learning Java based on the book by Herbert Schildt "Java The Complete Reference Tenth Edition". I’m working on a Java program with multiple threads, and I'm expecting the output to be in a specific order, but I’m getting different results. I’m using a synchronized method to control access to shared resources, but the order of output is not as I anticipated.
Code:
class Callme {
    synchronized void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    Callme target;
    Thread t;

    public Caller(Callme targ, String s) {
        target = targ;
        msg = s;
        t = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        target.call(msg);
    }
}

class Synch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Callme target = new Callme();
        Caller hello = new Caller(target, "Hello");
        Caller synch = new Caller(target, "Synchronized");
        Caller world = new Caller(target, "World");

        hello.t.start();
        synch.t.start();
        world.t.start();

        try {
            hello.t.join();
            synch.t.join();
            world.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}

In the book the expected output is this:
[Hello] [Synchronized] [World]
But I have this:
[Hello] [World] [Synchronized]
Question:
Could someone explain why I’m seeing this behavior? Is there something I’m missing with thread synchronization that’s affecting the order of execution?
What I’ve Tried:
I tried adjusting the order of start() and join() calls, but the issue persists. I also tried to create a thread using Thread inheritance instead of implementing Runnable.

This code just makes sure the threads don't run at the same time. There's nothing controlling the order in which they execute.

I copied your example 1:1 into a new project (in Eclipse). I moved each class into its' own file. I then ran Synch in a Java 17 environment. The result was [Hello] [Synchronized] [World].


Could someone explain why I’m seeing this behavior?

Nothing in the Java Language Specification or the Javadocs say the threads will run in any particular order.  Indeed, if you run the code repeatedly and/or on other platforms, you could get the output that you are expecting some of the time.
But the explanation of why you are getting a particular order (more often that some other order) will depend on all sorts of things, such as the behavior of the OS's native thread scheduler.

Is there something I’m missing with thread synchronization that’s affecting the order of execution?

No.  Thread synchronization doesn't come into this.  Or at least ... thread synchronization as implemented by your example doesn't come into it.

I tried adjusting the order of start() and join() calls, but the issue persists. I also tried to create a thread using Thread inheritance instead of implementing Runnable.

Correct.  None of those things are sufficient to cause the threads to run in a predictable order.  (And declaring a subclass of Thread is a bad idea for other reasons.)

There are lots of possible ways to make your example "work", but they will involve threads waiting for other threads to reach a particular state; i.e. actual synchronization.  (For example you could use a Phaser or a CountDownLatch.)
However ... I put it to you that getting these threads to execute in a particular order is probably defeating the point of using threads.  (At least in this example).  And to illustrate, a simple way to get the messages in the expected order would be:
    Callme target = new Callme();
    Caller hello = new Caller(target, "Hello");
    Caller synch = new Caller(target, "Synchronized");
    Caller world = new Caller(target, "World");

    hello.run();
    synch.run();
    world.run();

i.e. call run() on the current thread, not on child threads.

And note, if that books claims the output is guaranteed to be in that exact order for this exact snippet of code, the book is just plain wrong and probably worthless because that's quite a basic thing to get so wrong. Java has never guaranteed this order; there is no reasonable explanation I can think of for a tutorial book to claim that the order of print is guaranteed here. Of course, it might not be that dramatic: Perhaps the book doesn't claim any order and you misread that part, for example.

After hello is started the target.call enters the synchronized region where it stays for 1000 ms. Both synch and world will then also enter call but immediately their thread will go asleep. After hello's call ends, a next thread will be wakened to execute call.
However there is no guarantee on the order: that the threads are awakened in the order they were sent to sleep.
Such cases of injustice might lead to phenomena called race condition, fairness and other descriptions you will encounter.
Mind that a naive java implementation probably will yield "hello-synch-world." That hello came first is not mandatory, but natural as that code is encountered first.
As this is misleading, sometimes the implementation take a small code dance (like at parallelStream I believe).

If you want to guarantee order of execution of code between multiple threads, one way to achieve that is by using Semaphore. In the below code, only after printing [Hello], [Synchronized] will be printed and at last [World] will be printed.
[Hello] [Synchronized] [World]

So even if the thread2 and thread3 gets to execute before thread1, thread2 and thread3 will be blocked until thread1 release the lock for thread2.
Similarly thread3 will be blocked until thread2 release the required lock by thread3.
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore hello = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore synchronize = new Semaphore(0);
    Semaphore world = new Semaphore(0);

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        hello.acquire();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.print("[Hello] ");
      synchronize.release();
    });

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        synchronize.acquire();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.print("[Synchronized] ");
      world.release();
    });

    Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        world.acquire();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.print("[World]");
      world.release();
    });

    thread3.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread1.start();
    
    try {
        thread3.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread1.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    
  }
}

